# How to prevent an undefined scrollLeft, when scrolling vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to keep a div's position fixed, when scrolling vertically, but when scroll horizontally it should follow. I used this jquery script:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
$(".navback").css('left',-$(window).scrollLeft()+10);
});
```

It works, but only as long as the window is smaller than the div. If the window is bigger (and therefore not scrollable to the left) scrollLeft is undefined and my div is shifted to the side, when scrolling vertically. 
So how can I define scrollLeft in this case?

Comment: Simply not set the `left` CSS property if `$(window).scrollLeft()` is undefined? That way its horizontal position doesn't change at all if there's no horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: `scrollLeft` should return `0` not `undefined`. _... if the element is not scrollable, this number will be 0._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(window).scrollLeft()` should not return undefined, it should be zero. BUT to answer your question

```
var left = $(window).scrollLeft() || 0;
$(".navback").css('left',-left+10);
```

OR

```
var left = $(window).scrollLeft();
if(left !== undefined) {
    $(".navback").css('left',-left+10);
}
```

Comment: It still does not work. The strange thing is, even if i put an alert inside that if-not-undefined condition, i get that alert and it tells me: undefined.     `var left = $(window).scrollLeft();
      if(left !== undefined) {
       alert(window.scrollLeft),
          $(".navback").css('left',-left+10);
      }`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1Blerk/eLBS8/   But it produces lots of alerts, which is a bit annoying.

Comment: Look at what you are alerting! `alert(window.scrollLeft)` !== `$(window).scrollLeft()`~

Comment: NO, window.scrollLeft is not the same thing as $().scrollLeft(). You are alerting the WRONG THING. `$(window).scrollLeft()` is `0` and `window.scrollLeft` is `undefined`.

Comment: ok. thanks. The original problem was somewhere else and I didnt realize because i thought those two things are the same.